# Formulas breaking upon Row Insertions and Deletions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How can we tell Excel to keep **relative** references no matter what (after insertions and deletions)?

I have a simple checkbook-like sheet.
Column C for Refunds, D for Expenses (entered with a negative) and column E for a Running Balance.

Currently using the following formula for the Running Balance

```
=E16+C17+D17
```

like so
[image]

which however breaks all the time, like after certain row insertions and I have to copy paste the formula to fix column E.

The formula breaks like so: 
[image]

To reproduce the issue
select row 17, then control-shift-+, Excel changes the formula at E18 to

```
E16+C18+D18
```

and not

```
E17+C18+D18
```

I hacked the following (A)

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("E"&ROW()-1),INDIRECT("C"&ROW()),INDIRECT("D"&ROW()))
```

But it still fails upon row insertion 
(for instance, select row 17, then control-shift-+, Excel 2010 reverts to inserting in, the now blank row 17, with the following formula at E17
=E16+C17+D17  (instead of using my formula (A) )

How can I fix this and make it less error prone?
Thank you

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "keep relative references". Did you perhaps mean ""keep absolute references"? What do you want e.g. =E16+C17+D17 to become after; 1) One row is inserted before row 16; 2) Two rows are inserted before row 16; 2) Ten rows are inserted before row 16?

Comment: I typically insert a single row (usually to keep dates ordered or blank rows to keep activities apart visually :).  But regardless of how many rows are inserted, the cells in column E (or at least the one bound by the table) should *always* say add cell above + cell to-the-left + cell to-the-left-left.  I hope this is clear.  (I am using a table, but now always adding rows with pressing the TAB key at its bottom-right corner).

Comment: so if the row above is blank you would still add the empty cell or would you want the 2nd line above skipping the blank row?

Comment: Yes, I have a blank row for that just below the headings.  Apparently, using functions like Sum() instead of + -, handles spaces in cells and also avoid #value showing up.

Comment: But the insertion of rows by hitting TAB at the bottom-right corner will do precisely that, i.e. maintain the relative-referencing of formulas within a column. So, assuming that the formula =E16+C17+D17 is in row 17, then, after one row insertion, it will move down to row 18 and the formula for that row will be =E17+C18+D18. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @XORLX E16 stays and does not switch to E17.

Comment: @XORLX, yes if you use always the bottom corner with TAB key to insert the formula is good. However if I go in the middle of my table say select row 17, then control-shift-+, excel changes the formula at E18 to 
E16+C18+D18 and not E17+C18+D18, see snapshot in updated main body post.

Comment: you can use `$` in front of the rows or colums that you want to staw the same `=E$16+C17+D17`

Comment: @Marie. Yes, but you have the option here to click on the green triangle and correct this via Restore to Calculated Column Formula.

Comment: Agreed that to do this each time you insert a new row is a little annoying though, so you may wish to go with Scott's solution. Can't seem to see a way to change the default behaviour here, though I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: @XORLX, thank you, yes, I noticed that option. But of course we don't want that, stinking-vanilla relative notation =E16+C17+D17, do we.  If that what annoying upper left green triangle is about, we can ignore it.

Comment: In accrual accounting, why can't you simple take a total of columns C & D, possibly with a forwarding balance? Trying to pickup the last calculated total from column E seems to be what is fouling things up.

Comment: @Jeeped. can  you please elaborate, perhaps with an example. Thank you.

Comment: Your example is not complete enough to generate an example from.

Comment: @Jeeped, Column A has Dates, B transaction notes, C Refunds, D Expenses, E is a running balance.  I like C and D separate visually.  What else do you need to know.  We are just trying to keep a running balance formula in E that does not break upon insertions.  How else would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula seems to work for me:

```
=INDEX(E:E,ROW()-1)+INDEX(C:C,ROW())+INDEX(D:D,ROW())
```

[image]

As you can see by adding the row the formula stayed the same and referenced the correct number.

Comment: Same as @brucewayne answer, once you insert a row Excel switches formula to =E16+C17+D17, in the new row only.

Comment: I do not think I understand, the formula switched from mine to `=E16+C17+D17`?  That's not possible.  This will always reference E one row up and C and D on the same row, no matter how many rows are inserted or deleted.  It will never be static rows, but relative to the row in which the formula is placed.

Comment: so I repeated and took your formula and paste it in my first row of data at 6E, then copied it down a bunch of rows to E20, everything is fine.  Now select row 17, shift-control-+, now excel at E17 shows =E16+C17+D17 instead of your formula, which I would have accepted as a solution.  I am using Excel 2010. Aren't you getting the same behavior?

Comment: no, not at all, It should not be doing that.  Are you in a structured table?  Do you have any events in vba that would override the formula.  This is not normal behavior. @Marie

Comment: No I don't have any VBA code in my document.  I don't know about "structured" all I did is start using tables by means of selecting my data, then select format as table after watching some videos.  This provided the automatic handling when inserting at the bottom via the TAB key. But, I still run into the running balance formulas column E getting skewed.  BTW, I even copied your formula all the way to the end row of the table, thinking Excel may be using the formula from the last row of the table while inserting in the middle of table. But that was not the bug.

Comment: BTW, all cells with your formula are showing the green triangle "this cell is inconsistent with the column formula", I don't get that complaint, yet :)

Comment: It is your computer.  try turning it off and on again.  I just added a picture to show that it works.

Comment: Re "then copied it down a bunch of rows to E20", you have to copy it to ALL rows within the table.

Comment: However, you may want to see my last comment to your original post.

Comment: @ScottCraner, turn off the computer, that's a good one, I run for weeks, until Gates forces me reboot :),  I believe it's working for you, but I have NO idea why in my document it's replacing with relative notation upon row insertion. I am going to check excel settings in case there is anything about that, am I starting to loose it :)

Comment: @ScottCraner, I started a NEW book, added some headings at row 2, selected the headings row and some rows below them, then format as table, then pasted your formula  at E4 (skipping first row as you did in your snapshot at row 6) and copied it down to last row of said formatted table.  Now, it's even weirder, whether I use the TAB key on the last row or insert a row in the middle, I get a "blank" cell at E.  Does that shed any light?  Would you like me to provide a video :) ?

Comment: @ScottCraner, I am going to accept your formula as an answer, eventhough I have not looked up what INDEX() actually means :), I have discovered the problem to be with my Excel 2010, it does not behave like your Excel 2013.  I was able to verify what you are seeing on a different computer with Excel 2013.  So they (MS) must have changed these weird behaviors between 2010 and 2013 revisions.  Thank for all the others who pitched in.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

`=Indirect("E16")+Indirect("C17")+Indirect("D17")`?

Comment: It does not seem to adjust when I try to copy the formula to the cells below (or above) as if the references are absolute (hard-coded)